# Android run build error: When implement Inappmessaging-display

Tags: java, android, build, dependencies

After update `compileSdkVersion` to `28`; `buildToolsVersion` to `28.0.2`

I got this problem

> Learn how to resolve the issue at
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
>   Program type already present: io.reactivex.BackpressureStrategy   at
>   com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor269.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)

I already read here: 
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes
It's says:

> - A binary dependency includes a library that your app also includes as    a direct dependency.
> - For example, your app declares a direct dependency on Library A and
>        Library B, but Library A already includes Library B in its binary.
> - To resolve this issue, remove Library B as a direct dependency.
> - Your app has a local binary dependency and a remote binary
>        dependency on the same library.
> - To resolve this issue, remove one of the binary dependencies.

Here are my dependencies:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) // Android support libraries
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3"

    // Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'

    // Animators
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.3.0'

    // Android in app billing library
    implementation 'org.solovyev.android:checkout:1.2.1'

    // Butter knife
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

I don't know which one is included and which one includes. Super appreciate for anyone give me a solution, thanks.

**ADDED:**
I found that, I got this error after I implement this one:

> com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.1

Comment: 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.1' use similar version 16, it might help you.

Comment: what do you mean ? I couldn't get it

Comment: is there any other message then this compilation error ? Please check your event log while building app.do clean project and check what error is coming in event log.

Comment: So what the heck did I show you up there ?

Comment: I knew that I got this error when I implement : com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.1

Have another one have the same io.reactivex.BackpressureStrategy, but I really don't know how to fix it

Comment: ok, attach full build.gradle file. i will try in it !

Comment: Here is my build.gradle : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1z9KXKaBdOCuoRq4brS5stvja_PJz18Om